# SurfaceView проблемы с отображением цветов

Tags: java, android

Доброго  времени  суток
Есть FrameLayoyt  его  фон  залит  цветом  #FFF34135
Есть  SurfaceView  в  нем  цвет канвы  заливаю  argb  255,243,65,53 (соответствует  #FFF34135)

Вопрос  в  том  что  цвета  немного  не совпадают. На  норм  экранах  не  сильно  в  глаза  бросается,  а  вот  на  низком  разрешении режет  глаз. 
Как  добиться  совпадения?

пробовал  сделать  SurfaceView  прозрачным  но  тогда  появляются  проблемы  со  сглаживанием  и  вообще  с  отрисовкой